# How to use i18next with remix-typescript and have autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, i18next

I have remix app (Bluestack). I am using i18next for internationalisation. I want to have autocomplete feature while using keys from `index.json` similar to how typescript shows suggestion when type is defined.

I have tried https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript whats given over here but the it's not working. In docs it's mentioned to create that file in `src` folder but in remix app there is no such directory. Where exactly do i have to keep that file? What am i missing?

Package versions:

```
"@remix-run/express": "^1.6.0",
"react-i18next": "^11.18.6"
"@remix-run/node": "^1.6.0",
"@remix-run/react": "^1.6.0",
"@remix-run/server-runtime": "^1.6.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-i18next": "^11.18.6"
```

This my directory structure. translation file is inside the `public/locales/english/en/index.json`

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why the documentation says to augment `'react-i18n'`, but when I `declare module 'i18next' {` instead of `'react-i18n'`, it works for me with remix, too.